# How to pass a prefix argument to helm-m-x?

Tags: helm, prefix-argument

I have read the prefix has to be added after running `helm-m-x`, but I don't know how to do it.

For example I want to pass an argument to `shell`. When I run `helm-m-x` and then <kbd>C-u</kbd> I see in the mode-line *[prefarg:4]*. On the next key press there will be 4 occurrences of the key instead of only the first one.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`helm-M-x` is arguably unusual in this aspect.  You first invoke it, type until you've picked the command you want to execute, then add the prefix argument by pressing `C-u`.